# Is it possible to display the element when aria-checked = true?

Tags: javascript

I am new here.

I want to make a condition if the user clicks an option and the aria-checked is true then I want to display an element to block which by default I set to none.

The element display to none works, but displaying it to block does not work. Does anyone have any idea? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('wapf');
for (var i=0;i<elems1.length;i+=1){
    elems1[i].style.display = 'none';
}

var elems2 = document.getElementsByClassName('button-variable-item-resize');
var object = elems2.getAttribute("aria-checked");
for (var r=0;r<elems2.length;r+=t){
    if (object[r] == true){
    elems1[r].style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line returns an array:

```
var elems2 = document.getElementsByClassName('button-variable-item-resize');
```

So this line won't work because the `.getAttribute` property doesn't exist on arrays:

```
var object = elems2.getAttribute("aria-checked");
```

Instead, you should move that code inside the for loop like so:

```
for (var r=0;r<elems2.length;r+=t){
    var object = elems2[r].getAttribute("aria-checked");
    if (object == true){
    elems1[r].style.display='block';
}
```